# Undefined offset when printing elements of an array

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code:

```
$items_query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM Items_Orders NATURAL JOIN Items
                                    WHERE order_id="'.$order->order_id.'"');

    if(!$items_query)
    {
        echo 'MySQL error: '.mysql_error();
        die();
    }

    //add each item to the order
    while($items_row = mysql_fetch_array($items_query))
    {
        echo "item: ";

        for($i = 0; $i < count($items_row); $i++)
        {
            echo $items_row[$i];
        }   
    }
```

When the elements of the items_row are printed, my code iterates beyond the bounds of items row.  I am confused at why this is.  I explicitly define i to only iterate up to the size of items_row.  What's going on here?

Comment: Please note that mysql_* functions are deprecated.  Mysqli and PDO are the recommended way to handle mysql database connections.

Answer (score 3):

You are counting double length, because by default, you are getting named an numbered values. Try the following

```
while($items_row = mysql_fetch_array($items_query, MYSQL_NUM))
{
    echo "item: ";

    for($i = 0; $i < count($items_row); $i++)
    {
        echo $items_row[$i];
    }   
}
```

See [offical docs](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array)

P.S. mysql_* is deprecated, look into PDO object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query,MYSQL_NUM)){
   $count = count($row);
   for($i = 0;$i < $count;$i++){
       echo $row[$i];
   }
}
```

But your code is very dirty, why you do not use PDO ? Is the fast way how to make escaped queries... [PDO manual](https://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)